# Symfony & NTLM - Apache header authorization missing

Tags: apache, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm running Symfony 3.4 LTS and I have an issue when I try to use NTLM authentification.

For the record, on my server I get :

- a wordpress website
- a TYPO3 website
- and my new SYMFONY website

The Wordpress and Typo3 use NTLM authentification with :

```
<?php

$headers = apache_request_headers();
// then $headers['Authorization'] contains a big string with all the needed datas

?>
```

.. but I can't use this script on Symfony because there is no Authorization header return by the `apache_request_headers()` function. I made some searches in Stack Overflow but nothing helped me to fix my issue.

I tried :

- Add new directives in my htaccess : `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)` `RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]` .. and also `SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0`
- Work with $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] (this var is missing)
- Use a bundle (the only one I found only runs on Symfony 2.x)
- Use the Request with `$request->headers->all()` but the `Authorization` parameter is still missing

Do you have any idea ?
By the way, I don't want to edit my vhost file because my 2 other websites work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In my code, I added :

```
<?php

        if (!isset($headers['Authorization']))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
            header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');
            exit;
        }
```

.. right after the `apache_request_headers()` function. Now I got access to the `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using php-fpm and not mod_php.

Are you missung this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

in your apache config before the FPM handler?

Comment: I do not use "php-fpm"

Comment: I try to add "SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1" in htaccess, no effect at all on apache headers.